# SQL: Select Rows in Descending Order by Column2 and Only Show 1 Result When Column1 is not NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

Id -- Column1 -- Column2 -- ....

I want to select all rows in descending order by Column2 where Id = 1234 and Column1 is NULL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE Id = 1234 AND Column1 is NULL 
ORDER BY column2 DESC
```

PLUS

1 rows with largest value in Column2 where Id = 1234 and Column1 is not NULL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE Id = 1234 AND Column1 is NOT NULL 
ORDER BY column2 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

How to combine those two SQL queries into one?

Comment: Combining them will still give you the same result, it'll give you one row with two columns where the ID=1234 or an error because the query would be redundant because your checking for null and against it. There shouldn't be multiple rows with the same ID. Consider changing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION Syntax:

> `UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements
>   into a single result set.
>
> The column names from the first `SELECT` statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each `SELECT` statement should have the same
>   data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first
>   statement should have the same type as the first column selected by
>   the other statements.)

Let's build out a demo table for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for my_table
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Column1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of my_table
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '5', '6');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '6', '2');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '7', '0');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '8', '21');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '9', '4');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', '12', '3');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', null, '8');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', null, '22');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', null, '19');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1234', null, '0');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', '15', '2');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', '8', '5');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', '7', '100');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', '2', '7');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', null, '1');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('1235', null, '0');
```

We can now combine your two queries using `UNION` and dropping the `ORDER BY` in your statements as we're going to apply that to the `UNION`. Notice that I've used [MAX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) to determine the maximum value for `column2` where `Column1` is not `NULL`. This is what we get:

```
(SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `Id` = '1234' AND `Column1` IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT `Id`, `Column1`, MAX(`column2`) FROM `my_table` WHERE `Id` = '1234' AND `Column1` IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY `column2` DESC
```

Which give us the following result:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| Id   | Column1 | column2 |
+------+---------+---------+
| 1234 | NULL    |      22 |
| 1234 | 5       |      21 |
| 1234 | NULL    |      19 |
| 1234 | NULL    |       8 |
| 1234 | NULL    |       0 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Learn a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `UNION ALL` statement you can merge two different query result.

`ALL` option in `UNION` statement doesn't remove duplicated row. This, because you'll get the maximum value of column2 in the first query too.

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(SELECT id, column1, column2 
FROM my_table 
WHERE Id = 1234 AND Column1 is NULL 
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, column1, column2 
FROM my_table 
WHERE Id = 1234 AND Column1 is NOT NULL 
ORDER BY column2 DESC 
LIMIT 1)) as t
ORDER BY t.column2 DESC
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a15/5/0)

Comment: Incorrect usage of `UNION` and `ORDER BY`. You'll get an error.

Comment: @Daerik: I've fixed my answer. Thanks to feedback

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the link! I never knew there was a SQL Fiddle! This would make my demonstrations so much easier.

Comment: Thanks! Learn a lot!